# Click button and after refresh click button from new page

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a script for a game. Where I have to make just 2 clicks, but they are on different pages.

On page 1 I click on "Send"

```
javascript:document.getElementById('send').click();
```

When i click on that button, my page redirect to a "confirm" page. Where i need to click "Ok" button.

How can i do to click my first button and after redirect "auto click" the "Ok" button from the new page?

Comment: Lol sounds like a malware author's dream

Comment: You'll want to do it on document.ready, see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Answer (score 0):

If you also own the second page, you can have the `window.onload` method check against the url, for example look for the query string `?clickthrough=true` (which your first page redirects to) and if it exists simulate a click of the button.

E.g., first page redirects to `/second?clickthrough=true`, and your javascript on the second page checks the url like this:

```
if (window.location.href.split("?").slice(-1)[0] == "clickthrough=true")
  // click the button
```

---

If you do not own the second page, then I'd hope there is no way to do this as it would suddenly open users to a whole host of vulnerabilities.